# Getting an PDF from external webservice and store it as attachment creates empty pdf

Tags: apex, pdf, httpresponse

I have to get a pdf from an external web service and store it as an attachment of an object.

Im getting the pdf with the following code

```
public override Blob getPDFReport(String token, String jobId) {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod(METHOD_GET);
    req.setEndpoint(DOMAIN + PDF_REPORT_SERVICE + jobId);
    req.setHeader(HEAD_CONNTENT, 'application/pdf');
    //req.setHeader(HEAD_ACCEPT, JSON_TYPE);
    //req.setHeader(HEAD_VERSION, API_1_16_6);
    req.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding','chunked');
    req.setHeader('X-Content-Type-Options','nosniff');
    String tokenHeadValue = TOKEN_AUTH.replace(REPLACE_TOKENID, token);
    req.setHeader(HEAD_AUTH, tokenHeadValue);
    HTTPResponse res = this.sendRequest(req);
    for(String key : res.getHeaderKeys()) {
        System.debug(key + ' ->' + res.getHeader(key));
    }
    Blob body = res.getBodyAsBlob();

    return body;
}
```

Then Im trying to run an apex anonymous for debugging

```
Blob b = api.getPDFReport('eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NTkzOTgwMTgsImlhdCI6MTU1NjgwNjAxOCwiaXNzIjoiYXV0aDpwcm9kdWN0aW9uIiwic2VyYTpzaWQiOiJjZmEwNGQ4Zi01YTUzLTQ2ZGYtYjdiMi0zZThmY2RiOWI5NjMiLCJzZXJhOnR5cCI6ImF1dGgiLCJzdWIiOiIzNGZjNzYxZi1hNzM3LTRjMTYtYmIzNC1lNDBhZjczNjQzMTkifQ.qf0Ztxq84ZZYIGI4W_HwhhcN64IMY8yh0Ogi8YyJK60',
                      '7f194a97-743d-412b-a54b-4b97c0abcb0a');

System.debug(b);

Attachment attach = new Attachment();
attach.Body = b;
attach.Name = String.valueOf('test.pdf');
attach.ParentId = '5005B000005NzihQAC';

insert attach;
```

The System.debug(b) is showing that the result is not empty and all the response headers are correct. But the attachment is empty.

Have anyone faced some similar situation?